# Converting from array to float[]

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine

How?

Error happens with this line:

```
PlayerPrefsX.SetFloatArray("PIKE0_x",vars.SAmericaInf_x);
```

vars.SAmericaInf_x is defined like that:

```
static var SAmericaInf_x = new Array();
```

***Error is stated as:
assets/scripts/Core/Core.js(156,51): BCE0017: The best overload for the method 'PlayerPrefsX.SetFloatArray(String, float[])' is not compatible with the argument list '(String, Array)'.***

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be specifying the *type* of your array when you declare it, according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) documentation:

```
static var SAmericaInf_x = new Float32Array();
```

You can find the summary for this type [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Float32Array)